# Fullcalendar - Disable overlapping events

Tags: fullcalendar

I have a calendar that displays appointments for particular person.  How do I set fullcalendar up so that events on the calendar can not overlap each other?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to prevent overlapping events in jQuery FullCalendar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369683/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-overlapping-events-in-jquery-fullcalendar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var events = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');

// start-time in between any of the events
if(eventStartDay > events[i].start && eventStartDay < events[i].end){
    return true;
}
//end-time in between any of the events
if(eventEndDay > events[i].start && eventEndDay < events[i].end){
    return true;
}
//any of the events in between/on the start-time and end-time
if(eventStartDay <= events[i].start && eventEndDay >= events[i].end){
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Check those conditions after putting them inside a function and call that function while create/update of an event! 
I was troubled with the same issue :) 
Hope it gives atlest some idea.

Answer (score 6):

When selecting you can disabled the overlap:

```
selectOverlap: false
```

When you drag&drop:

```
eventOverlap: false
```

Answer (score 5):

This option was incorporated since 2.20

```
eventOverlap: false
```

http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_ui/eventOverlap/

Comment: The link is broken. I guess it now is https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventOverlap

Answer (score 0):

I guess the easiest way to achieve this is to manipulate the event source. That is if you're using a source that is changeable.

Answer (score 0):

Following options were helpful imc:

```
eventOverlap={false}
slotEventOverlap={false}
```