# Can I prevent events with conflict time?

Tags: fullcalendar

How can I prevent events with conflict time? Is there any variable to set up?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to prevent overlapping events in jQuery FullCalendar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369683/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-overlapping-events-in-jquery-fullcalendar)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, there is not a variable to set, but you can use something like [clientEvents](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/clientEvents/) which retrieves events that fullcalendar has in memory. You can use the function below in the [eventDrop](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_ui/eventDrop/). In the case below it uses a function to filter out whether the event will have have an overlap or not.

```
function checkOverlap(event) {  

    var start = new Date(event.start);
    var end = new Date(event.end);

    var overlap = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents', function(ev) {
        if( ev == event)
            return false;
        var estart = new Date(ev.start);
        var eend = new Date(ev.end);

        return (Math.round(estart)/1000 < Math.round(end)/1000 && Math.round(eend) > Math.round(start));
    });

    if (overlap.length){  
            //either move this event to available timeslot or remove it
       }                  
  }
```

Comment: Awesome, any suggestions on how I could adapt this to work on dayClick?

Answer (score 2):

you can add eventOverlap : false in the celendar config, 
http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_ui/eventOverlap/

Comment: This only works for the v2 fullcalendar, whereas it looks like the other two work with v1 as well as v2.

Answer (score 1):

Correct overlap checking.

```
        eventDrop: function(event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, allDay, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view) {
            /// deny overlap of event
            var start = new Date(event.start);
            var end = new Date(event.end);

            var overlap = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents', function(ev) {
                if( ev == event) {
                    return false;
                }
                var estart = new Date(ev.start);
                var eend = new Date(ev.end);

                return (
                    ( Math.round(start) > Math.round(estart) && Math.round(start) < Math.round(eend) )
                    ||
                    ( Math.round(end) > Math.round(estart) && Math.round(end) < Math.round(eend) )
                    ||
                    ( Math.round(start) < Math.round(estart) && Math.round(end) > Math.round(eend) )
                );
            });
            if (overlap.length){
                revertFunc();
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add custom property in the event object `overlap:false`  for example your event object will be

```
                 `{
                    title:'Event',
                    start: '2017-01-04T16:30:00',
                    end: '2017-01-04T16:40:00',
                    overlap:false
                  }`
```

Now override selectOverlap function,

```
selectOverlap: function(event) {
    if(event.ranges && event.ranges.length >0) {
      return (event.ranges.filter(function(range){
          return (event.start.isBefore(range.end) &&
                  event.end.isAfter(range.start));
      }).length)>0;
    }
    else {
      return !!event && event.overlap;
    }
  },
```

It will not let the another event to override the already placed event.

Answer (score 1):

This does the trick. It also handles resizing overlapping events

```
var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
      selectOverlap: false,
      eventOverlap: false
  }
});
```