# jQuery FullCalendar plugin with Room reservation system

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullcalendar

I'm using [FullCalendar ResourceViews](http://tux.fi/~jarnok/fullcalendar-resourceviews/) plugin for my reservation project and its working perfectly :D

The problem is overlapping. Yes there is more question in stackoverflow about overlapping. But mine is little different.

I've modified the [overlapping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8796793/1113356) function for Resource Views plugin.

```
function isOverlapping(event,calendar){
    var array = calendar.fullCalendar('clientEvents');
    console.log(array)
    for( i in array ) {
        if( array[i].resource != event.resource ){
            if( !(array[i].start >= event.end || array[i].end <= event.start) ){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

But my problem is I cannot allow to book the same room for same date range. Please visit my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kcxPp/) here. You can see my problem clearly

Comment: Before starting myself. Have you released your room reservation system anywhere?