# Fullcalendar event overlapping issues

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, dom-events

```
function isOverlapping(event){
    var array = calendar.fullCalendar('clientEvents');
    for(i in array){
        if(array[i].id != event.id){
            if(!(Date(array[i].start) >= Date(event.end) || Date(array[i].end) <= Date(event.start))){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

In the fullcalendar, I want to prevent the overlap among the events when dropping an *external* event on to the calendar.

When I drag or resize the event in the calendar, this function is working, 
but when I drop an external event on to the calendar it is allowing the events to be overlapped. Why is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: You may find the answer you need in this discussion:

<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369683/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-overlapping-events-in-jquery-fullcalendar>