# FullCalendar eventDrop should be full day

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

In this following Sample,

http://travelhatke.com/demo/fullcalendar/demos/spdemo.html

I need the events to be full day always.

i.e, If an event is overlapped on drop, it should move to next available full day slot...

The final result should be that event should always be full day.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Go step by step for this.

1. on drop function of calendar use -> copiedEventObject.allDay = true;
2. Then check for overlapping  events follow this link [click here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369683/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-overlapping-events-in-jquery-fullcalendar)
3. If overlapping increment the date object by 1 and then place it.

I hope it might help.